# What is the difference between "dnl" and "dnl #" in a sendmail.mc file?

Tags: sendmail

What is the difference between `dnl` and `dnl #` in a `/etc/mail/sendmail.mc` file? If I want to enable something what needs to be in front?  Likewise, if I want to "comment out" something, what prefix do I need?

For example:

```
dnl # masquerade not just @mydomainalias.com, but @*.mydomainalias.com as well
dnl #
dnl FEATURE(masquerade_entire_domain)dnl
dnl #
dnl MASQUERADE_DOMAIN(localhost)dnl
dnl MASQUERADE_DOMAIN(localhost.localdomain)dnl
dnl MASQUERADE_DOMAIN(foo.com)dnl
dnl MASQUERADE_DOMAIN(foo2.lan)dnl
MAILER(smtp)dnl
MAILER(procmail)dnl
dnl MAILER(cyrusv2)dnl
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There's a subtle but important difference between `dnl` and `#` here.

`dnl` means ["delete through newline"](http://www.sendmail.com/sm/open_source/docs/m4/intro_m4.html). When you process your `sendmail.mc` into a `sendmail.cf` using `m4` (or possibly some frontend), the characters `dnl` and everything following them, *including* the next newline, will be dropped. (And all of those lines *end* with `dnl` to suppress extra blank lines in the `sendmail.cf` output.)

**Nothing beginning with `dnl` through end of line will make it out of `sendmail.mc` and into `sendmail.cf`.**

Anything that remains in the output, of course, will either be sendmail configuration, or a comment that begins with `#`, which will be copied as-is into `sendmail.cf`, where they will be ignored.

**Anything beginning with `#` and not deleted above will make it into `sendmail.cf` unmolested as a comment.**

In your example, someone meant for all of the commented features to be removed from `sendmail.cf`, as well as the comments, since the comments would be meaningless without the features present.

Comment: You don't _have_ to end a line with `dnl` but you'll end up with extra blank lines in `sendmail.cf`. And yes, if you want something to take effect, it must actually be present in `sendmail.cf`...

Comment: @MikeB m4 is case sensitive - `DNL` is not `dnl`.  Sorry but I have seen a few stupid m4 bugs in  answears with very high scores in Stack Exchange sites.

Comment: ... and so that means if I want an explicit configuration option to take effect it must NOT have `dnl` or `dnl #` in front of it...? and I'll want to always end it with dnl?

Comment: @AndrzejA.Filip Thanks.  The site wouldn't let me edit the question so I re-added it.

Comment: I find that a line beginning with `#` does not get copied as-is to sendmail.cf. Instead, the line is copied with only the `#` removed. Thus, a `#` line does not end up as a comment. (I was processing using `m4`.)

Answer (score 5):

DNL means "delete through newline" which really means "ignore everything after 'dnl' until the next line".

The "dnl #" is just artificial nomenclature.  When the sendmail.mc file was first developed they wanted you to know that anything that was "dnl ..." was a command/setting that was commented out and anything that was "dnl #..." was really a descriptive comment that was not a command/setting that could be uncommented because '#' is often used at the beginning of a line to indicate "what follows until end of line" is a comment.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, 8 years old, and no-one's ever going to read this, but I just wanted to point out that putting two `dnl`s on a line is completely pointless. It doesn't "suppress extra blank lines in the `sendmail.cf` output", as suggested above.

Since a picture is worth a thousand words:

```
$ m4 <<EOF 
Line 1
dnl Line 2 
Line 3
dnl Line 4 dnl
Line 5
# Line 6
Line 7
dnl # Line 8
Line 9
EOF
```

Produces this output:

```
Line 1
Line 3
Line 5
# Line 6
Line 7
Line 9
```